# Return a portion of a plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using SpanSelector but am trying to return a portion of the plot being modified by spanSelector.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, axisbg='#FFFFCC')

x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(x))

ax.plot(x, y, '-')
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_title('Press left mouse button and drag to test')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, axisbg='#FFFFCC')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, y, '-')


def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x)-1, indmax)

    thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
    thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
    print thisy
    line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
    ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
    ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min(), thisy.max())
    fig.canvas.draw()

# set useblit True on gtkagg for enhanced performance
span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                    rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red') )

plt.show()
```

Right now I only can print this part of the code being selected right now, but I want to return it to be used as a variable to have statistics made from it later in my code. Is this possible, or do I need to do any statistics calculations inside of the onselect function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new function:

```
def calc_stats(xs, ys):
    print 'doing the calculations'
```

and call this from within `onselect`:

```
def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x)-1, indmax)

    thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
    thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
    calc_stats(thisx, thisy)
    line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
    ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
    ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min(), thisy.max())
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Alternatively, you can store the result in a global dictionary.:

```
coords = {}

def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x)-1, indmax)

    thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
    thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
    coords['x'] = thisx
    coords['y'] = thisy
    line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
    ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
    ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min(), thisy.max())
    fig.canvas.draw()

# set useblit True on gtkagg for enhanced performance
span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                    rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red') )

plt.show()

print 'working with x an y'
print coords['x'][:10]
print coords['y'][:10]
```

Modifying a global dict is not really good style. This does the same but uses a class:

```
class Onselect():

    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = {}

    def __call__(self, xmin, xmax):
        indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
        indmax = min(len(x)-1, indmax)

        thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
        thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
        self.coords['x'] = thisx
        self.coords['y'] = thisy
        line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
        ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
        ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min(), thisy.max())
        fig.canvas.draw()

onselect = Onselect()

# set useblit True on gtkagg for enhanced performance
span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                    rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red') )

plt.show()

print 'working with x an y'
print onselect.coords['x'][:10]
print onselect.coords['y'][:10]
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking about doing. I just wasn't sure if there was any other way. Inside onselct I tried to make thisx or thisy global, then print it outside of everthing, why didn't that work?

Comment: You can also use a global datastructure such as dict. Se my updated answer.

Comment: Okay cool, I think I will still just do a statistics calculation inside the function but we'l see. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I just tested your second two examples and got key errors for both. I think this is because the onselect becomes a new input code, so there isn't anything in the dictionary to be outputted. I'm trying to have input for the statistics I'm doing in the onselect but can't figure out any way to do this because input is not allowed in it; I receive an error whenever I try.